# Can not get radio values in php

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

Okay this is kind of a noob question but I have been searching and searching and can not find out how to do this. I can not get the values of my radio buttons useing php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Do you buy your lunch?
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="doyoubuy" value="Yes" checked>Yes
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="doyoubuy" value="No">No
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if (isset($_POST['doyoubuy'])) {
                    echo "You have selected :".$_POST['doyoubuy'];
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are checking `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

But your submit button is not actually named...

So just name it:

`<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">`

Then your code for the radios should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The action should be the current page. In your case is ""

Comment: While technically invalid according to the HTML spec... the behaviour of all modern browsers is to submit to the current URL if the action is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this HTML and PHP for your consideration:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            Do you buy your lunch?
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="doyoubuy" value="Yes" checked>Yes
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="doyoubuy" value="No">No
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
        if (isset($_POST) && $_POST != NULL) {
          if ( $_POST['doyoubuy']  == 'Yes' || $_POST['doyoubuy'] == 'No') {
             $answer = $_POST['doyoubuy'];
             echo "You selected :". $answer;
          }
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

What needs to be tested is whether the form was submitted.  If so, provided that each field bears a name in the form, then a value of some kind will be associated with every field, which obviates the need to test if the submit button is set. Also, if a user submitted a form but neglected to fill in, for example, a text input, then that field's value would still be set; it would be set to an empty string.

It is inadvisable to trust a posted form value and consider it safe to use.  In this case, I test to be sure that the answer is what I'm expecting, just in case someone might have spoofed the form and changed the answer to something other than what I intended.

By default, if one leaves out the ACTION attribute of the form, its value is the url of the page containing the form.